# List Traversal in a lazy setting that produces expressions in WHNF

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, traversable

I simulate lazy evaluation, i.e. evaluate only when needed and only once, in JS with `Proxy` and run into a problem with Traversable (`mapA` instead of `traverse` at the term level):

```
const r = List.mapA({map: Opt.map, ap: Opt.ap, of: Opt.of})
  (x => (x & 1) === 0 ? null : x)
    (List.fromArr([1,3,5]));

Opt.map(Arr.fromList) (r); // yields [1,3,5]
```

Please note that `Opt` isn't an ADT but based on `null`. This works as expected: `r` is a thunk. `Arr.fromList` is strict and eventually forces evaluation of `r`. The problem arises when I trigger short circuiting, i.e. pass `List.fromArr([1,2,3])` to `List.mapA`. When `Opt.map` forces the evaluation of the outermost `List` layer it yields the first elem `1` and the tail of the list, which is an unevaluated thunk again. Hence `Opt.map` assumes continuous computation and applies `r` to `Arr.fromList`, which in turn forces the evaluation of the entire `List`. `2` causes the short circuiting but not within `Opt.map` but within `List.fromArr`. Hence an error is thrown.

The problem is that due to lazy evaluation the transformation of `r` from `List` to `null` is deferred and thus not handled by the `Opt` functor anymore but by the pure functon invoked by it. How does a lazy language like Haskell tackle this issue? Or am I making a mistake in between?

Unfortunately, I cannot provide a running example because it would include a huge amount of library code. Here are implementations of the core functions, in case someone is interested:

```
List.mapA = ({map, ap, of}) => {
  const liftA2_ = liftA2({map, ap}) (List.Cons);
  return f => List.foldr(x => acc =>liftA2_(f(x)) (acc)) (of(List.Nil));
};

const liftA2 = ({map, ap}) => f => tx => ty => ap(map(f) (tx)) (ty);

List.foldr = f => acc => function go(tx) { // guarded rec if `f` non-strict in 2nd arg
  return tx.run({
    nil: acc,
    cons: y => ty => f(y) (lazy(() => go(ty)))
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ thunk
  });
};
```

---

[EDIT]

Here is a more detailed description of the computation. A thunk is not just the usual nullary function `() => ..` but guarded by a `Proxy`, so that it can be used as a placeholder for any expression in most cases.

**Constructing `r`**

1. `List.fromArr` creates a List `{head: 1, tail}` with the tail fully evaluated
2. `List.mapA` applies the head `1` to its `f`, which yields `1` and the overall op in turn returns `{head: 1, tail: thunk}`, i.e. the tail is a thunk (since `1` is odd there is no short circuiting)
3. The evaluation stops because `List.foldr`, of which `List.mapA` is derived of, is non-strict in the tail
4. `r` evaluated to `{head: 1, tail: thunk}`, i.e. an expression that contains a thunk and is now in weak head normal form (WHNF) (and isn't a thunk itself as I claimed in my original question)
5. please note that there is no `Opt` layer because optional values are encoded using `null`, not as an ADT

**Convert the traversed list back to Array again**

1. Lifting the strict `Arr.fromList` with `Opt.map` is necessary because `r` may be `null`
2. `Opt.map` inspects the outermost layer of the list in WHNF `r`, so no further evaluation takes place at this point since the expression is already in WHNF
3. it detects a `List`, which is equivalent to `Just [a]`, and invokes the pure function `Arr.fromList` to further process `r`
4. `Arr.fromList` is strict, i.e. it recursively evaluates the tail until the base case is hit
5. during the second recursion it evaluates the tail, which is a thunk, to `{head: f(2), tail: thunk}`, where `f` is the one from `List.mapA`
6. `f(2)` evaluates to `null` and short circuits the original list traversal
7. `Arr.fromList` expects another list layer, not `null` and throws an error

I have a hunch that `List.mapA` must be strict in its list argument. I could easily do it, because there is a strict version of `foldr` based on tail recursion modulo cons. However, I doesn't understand the underlying principle when to make an operation strict. If list traversals were strict, so would have to be monadic list chains. That would be a bummer.

Comment: You'll need to post the definitions of *all* the functions you refer to in your question, not just the core ones, to make a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When `Opt.map` forces the evaluation of the outermost `List` layer it yields the first elem `1` and the tail of the list, which is an unevaluated thunk again.

Something is wrong here. `Opt.map` does not force the evaluation of the `List` layer, all it does is to force the evaluation of the `Opt` layer and leave the rest to the mapping callback. (Or really, `Opt.map` would return a thunk for this operation, it wouldn't do this immediately).

If you do

```
const r = List.mapA(Opt)(x => x & 1 ? x : null)(List.fromArr([1,2,3]))
```

then `r` already is `null` (or a thunk for it, if you want). Calling

```
Opt.map(Arr.fromList)(r)
```

on this will never even call `Arr.fromList`, it will just forward `null`.

If this is not what is happening in your code, there either is a bug in your lazy thunk implementation or in your `Opt` (`map`, `ap`, `of`) implementation.

---

Re update:

> 1. `List.fromArr` creates a List `{head: 1, tail}` with the tail fully evaluated
> 2. `List.mapA` applies the head `1` to its `f`, which yields `1` and the overall op in turn returns `{head: 1, tail: thunk}`, i.e. the tail
>    is a thunk (since `1` is odd there is no short circuiting)
> 3. The evaluation stops because `List.foldr`, of which `List.mapA` is derived of, is non-strict in the tail
> 4. `r` evaluated to `{head: 1, tail: thunk}`, i.e. an expression that contains a thunk and is now in weak head normal form (WHNF) (and isn't
>    a thunk itself as I claimed in my original question)

No no no. This sounds like you are confusing `List.mapA` with `List.map`. `mapA` *must* run through the entire list to apply the applicative effects before returning a result (though of course, it may return a thunk for this instead, but evaluating that to WHNF must distinguish between `Nothing` (`null`) and `Just`, where the contents of `Just` may be lazy still).

It doesn't matter that `foldR` does not evaluate the tail itself but only passes a thunk to `f`, it is the responsibility of `Opt.ap` to look at that second argument to check whether the tail of the list evaluates to `Nothing` or a `Just`.

> 5. please note that there is no `Opt` layer because optional values are encoded using `null`, not as an ADT

The layer is still there, even if `Just` is not represented by a separate JS value. Notice that this might be the reason for causing all this trouble, since it makes it hard (impossible?) to distinguish `thunk::Opt a` (which may evaluate to `null::Opt a`) from `(Just thunk)::Opt a`. Are you going to just make `Opt` strict?

> 2. `Opt.map` inspects the outermost layer of the list in WHNF `r`,
>    so no further evaluation takes place at this point since the
>    expression is already in WHNF
> 3. it detects a `List`

Why should it do that? All that `Opt.map` needs to do is check whether the outermost layer is `null` or not. It shouldn't further evaluate `Just` contents that are not in WHNF.

> I have a hunch that `List.mapA` must be strict in its list argument.

Yes, but this is not done by choosing a strict `foldR` variant. It is done by `liftA2`/`ap` forcing evaluation of the list tail.

Comment: I've not tested it yet but that's most likely it: _It is done by `liftA2/ap` forcing evaluation_. Among other things `Opt.ap` checks `thunk === null` and this should trigger evaluation of `thunk` to WHNF, but it doesn't, because the operator doesn't provide a trap the underlying proxy can hook into.

Comment: Kudos for finding the bug merely using human inference without looking into the code.

Comment: A possible fix would be using special `eq` op function that takes optional thunks into account. But the equality issue is a real pain and probably renders the whole idea of thunk based lazyness unviable.